# Canvas tag in Drupal 8

Tags: html, canvas, drupal, drupal-8

I want to ask does anybody knows if there exists a canvas html tag in Drupal 8?

Im trying to make signature form field so I need a canvas. Is there anyway to render custom HTML in Drupal 8 module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Canvas tag exists in Drupal 8. To use canvas in your code you need to use html_tag type. I wrote the following to create a canvas in my form. You can find the documentation at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21HtmlTag.php/class/HtmlTag/8.2.x.

I hope this works for you.

```
$form['canvas']=array(
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'canvas',
      '#attributes' => array(
                    'style'=>'border: 1px solid #000000;
                              width: 200;
                              height: 100;'
                            ),
      );
```

Comment: Can you provide an example or documentation on how to use the canvas tag in Drupal?